# I'm trying to integrate DHTMLX gantt with a Quasar project , and i'm getting a blank page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar

i did try to install the dependency on my quasar project , call the component and initialize a boot file , but i still get a blank page every single time , the only way it works is when i test it on a VUE 3 prject .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sizes (`width` and `height`) for the Gantt container and its parent elements when the sizes are relative:

```
#gantt_here{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

html,
body, 
#q-app,
#q-app > div,
.q-page-container {
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/faq.html#theganttchartisntrenderedcorrectly

Here is a Quasar demo with Vue 2 and Gantt 7.1.13:
https://files.dhtmlx.com/30d/a6d4aa45521cbe2de6f7f87901eeb693/quasar-project.zip